# Finding the value of cot 142.5°

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have seen a few solutions but I can't apply them to this particular question. The question is:

Prove that $\cot 142.5° = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - 2 -  \sqrt{6}$

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472594/prove-that-cot7-frac12-circ-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt4-sqrt6

Comment: I have seen this perticular solution... But I was wondering how to apply that in this case

Comment: @LeConnoisseur: so you are basically asking what is the relation between $\cot 7.5^\circ$ and $\cot (150-7.5)^\circ$, which should be simple to grasp.

Comment: So, $$\cot142.5^\circ=\dfrac{1+\cos285^\circ}{\sin285^\circ}$$  $$285=360-75,75=45+30$$

Answer (score 1):

use $$\cot(2x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cot(x)-1}{\cot(x)}$$ and $$\cot(285^{\circ})=\sqrt{3}-2$$